# D3 smooth country floating

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js

I have globe which is implemented using D3:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MeAA55fbY5dMZETCXpFo?p=preview

```
var width = 600,
  height = 500,
  sens = 0.25,
  focused;

//Setting projection

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
  .scale(245)
  .rotate([0, 0])
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
  .clipAngle(90);

var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

//SVG container

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

//Adding water

svg.append("path")
  .datum({
    type: "Sphere"
  })
  .attr("class", "water")
  .attr("d", path)
  .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function() {
      var r = projection.rotate();
      return {
        x: r[0] / sens,
        y: -r[1] / sens
      };
    })
    .on("drag", function() {
      var rotate = projection.rotate();
      projection.rotate([d3.event.x * sens, -d3.event.y * sens, rotate[2]]);
      svg.selectAll("path.land").attr("d", path);
      svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);
    }));

var countryTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "countryTooltip"),
  countryList = d3.select("body").append("select").attr("name", "countries");


queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "world.json")
  .defer(d3.tsv, "names.tsv")
  .await(ready);

//Main function

function ready(error, world, countryData) {

  var countryById = {},
    countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

  //Adding countries to select

  countryData.forEach(function(d) {
    countryById[d.id] = d.name;
    option = countryList.append("option");
    option.text(d.name);
    option.property("value", d.id);
  });

  //Drawing countries on the globe

  var world = svg.selectAll("path.land")
    .data(countries)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "land")
    .attr("d", path)

  //Drag event

  .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function() {
      var r = projection.rotate();
      return {
        x: r[0] / sens,
        y: -r[1] / sens
      };
    })
    .on("drag", function() {
      var rotate = projection.rotate();
      projection.rotate([d3.event.x * sens, -d3.event.y * sens, rotate[2]]);
      svg.selectAll("path.land").attr("d", path);
      svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);
    }))

  //Mouse events

  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      countryTooltip.text(countryById[d.id])
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 7) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 15) + "px")
        .style("display", "block")
        .style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      countryTooltip.style("opacity", 0)
        .style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      countryTooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 7) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 15) + "px");
    });

  //Country focus on option select

  d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
    var rotate = projection.rotate(),
      focusedCountry = country(countries, this),
      p = d3.geo.centroid(focusedCountry);

    svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);

    //Globe rotating

    (function transition() {
      d3.transition()
        .duration(2500)
        .tween("rotate", function() {
          var r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]]);
          return function(t) {
            projection.rotate(r(t));
            svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path)
              .classed("focused", function(d, i) {
                return d.id == focusedCountry.id ? focused = d : false;
              });
          };
        })
    })();
  });

  function country(cnt, sel) {
    for (var i = 0, l = cnt.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (cnt[i].id == sel.value) {
        return cnt[i];
      }
    }
  };

};
```

I want to add next effect: when a country is clicked, landmass for the country should float above the rest. As here:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6738360

I don't need complicated logic, just simple animation. When scale increases and shadow appears.

Spent few days on that, please help if you have some advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example in the second link, you need to plot the water and the land with different projection scales (the land projection is bigger).

Also, if you want a land to float above the rest, you need to bring it to the front (d3 does not support z-index and the elements are layered according to the order they are drawn).

First thing, you need to add the following function to your code (credit goes to [here](http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/4e0a69d57d3bfc8a82c2))

```
// Credit goes to http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/4e0a69d57d3bfc8a82c2
d3.se lection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {  
  return this.each(function(){
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};
```

This will give you the ability to move an element to the top.

The second part is to add a click event where you draw the countries:

```
clicked = null
var world = svg.selectAll("path.land")
     .data(countries)
     .enter().append("path")
     .attr("class", "land")
     .attr("d", path).on('click', function(){

          // Move the clicked land to the top
          d3.select(this).moveToFront()

          // Rescale the projection
          projection.scale(265)

         // Redraw the land with the new projection
         d3.select(this)
           .transition()
           .duration(500)
           .attr('d',path)

       // Changed back to original scale
       projection.scale(245)

      // Bring previous selected land to the original scale
      if (clicked != null)
         clicked.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr('d',path)

     // Store clicked scale
     clicked = d3.select(this)     
   })
};
```